# LabVIEW variables Find and Replace

Tags: variables, replace, labview

How do I make all variables bound to numeric control `a` point to numeric control `b` instead?

[image]

**Original question**

I have a two Queue Refnums: `old_queue` and `new_queue`.
    I have a two Queue Refnums: `old_queue` and `new_queue`.

How do I rebind all local variables bound to `old_queue` to `new_queue`?

Comment: I've taken the liberty of suggesting an edit to your title, as 'replace one reference with another' was a bit too generic (there are lots of different sorts of reference in LabVIEW!)

Comment: Another option, instead of using local variables use property nodes, value property and feed them the correct reference to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can rebind local variables from one control or indicator to another using VI Scripting. Place this code in a new VI:

[image: VI snippet to rebind local variables]

This opens a reference to the VI whose locals you want to rebind, gets a reference to the VI's front panel, gets a reference to the control on that front panel named `queue 1`, gets an array of references to the local variables of that control, and sets the `Control Name` property of each local to `queue 2`.

You need to enable `Show VI Scripting functions, properties and methods` in the `VI Server` section of LabVIEW's options in order to see the scripting properties and methods.

Comment: That's somewhere in the middle between what I've been hoping for and afraid of ;) Is there maybe a QuickDrop macro for that?

Comment: I've rephrased the question so that it would look more generic.

Comment: I don't know about a Quick Drop macro, but the image above is a VI snippet that you can drag on to the block diagram of a new VI and save for reuse any time. With a small amount of extra work you could turn that into a VI that shows a file dialog so you can choose the target VI, then shows a list of all the controls on that VI's panel so you can select which control's locals should be reassigned to which other control.

Comment: Yep, VI snippets are cool. And thanks for this one. But I have a fear deep inside that after n-th question of this kind I'll get an answer "I don't know about this feature of LabView but you can drag this c++ code into visual studio and with a small amount of work you could turn that into your own LabView implementation" ;)

Comment: Have you ever seen a (generic) GUI that doesn't have 'Search and Replace' feature? Would you choose such a GUI for work? It's all about monopoly...

Answer (score 0):

Just resaved the @nekomatic's code into LabView 2011 (for those who, like me, have to work with an old Labview version).

[image: LabView 2011]